# Setting up the appendix with memoir

Tags: spacing, sectioning, header-footer, memoir, appendices

I need some help setting up the layout for the appendix of a Thesis template I am working with Memoir Class. Before the appendix all the document have the following format

> Top, right and bottom margins 1in Left margin 1.5in Type Bock Size 9in
>   Distance from chapter title and top of the page 2in

The problem now is that on the appendix they are asking for something a little different

> Top, right and bottom margins 1in Left margin 1.5in Distance from
>   chapter title and top of the page 1in (Same font size as text)

Any successive pages from the appendix should have in the top Appendix A (cont.) and they should be 1in from the top of the page. I have tried many things without success. I will like to know if you have any ideas on how to solve this.

Comment: Why do they want different margins in different parts of the document. At present memoir does not provide any means for changing layout mid document. You may try the geometry package. May I ask who is asking this? University...? To me this seems to be a very strange rule.

Comment: @daleif: It doesn't look like the margins are supposed to be differnt; instead, they're asking for 1 inch instead of 2 inches of vertical space between the header line and the textblock (implying that the textblock should be 1in taller too, I suppose).

Comment: This is the formart from the university. Everything was perfect before the appendix. The problem is that when I add the header to include "Appendix A (cont.)" all gets messed up. I can set up manually the distance from the title of chapter to the top of the page to 1in. But once I try to fix any succesive pages all gets really bad. I havent worked with the geometry pakage, it is hard to do it?

Comment: @mico by margins I mean the distance from the paper edge to the textblock, this to be sounds like different margins.

Comment: @hector, could you please post a MWE, it is hard to know what you have tried without looking at some code.

Comment: I appologize for this but what is "MWE"?

Comment: Minimal working example, i.e. small document that can compile, which show your problem, or what you have done so far. By minimal, we mean the document should not contain irrelevant packages or macros

Comment: @Hector: See [I've just been told I have to write a minimal example, what is that?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) on how to create an MWE.

Comment: @Hector: If this question should get closed, but you want to extend it with a MWE, feel free to request its reopening at [meta].

Answer (score 2):

If you use the geometry package, you can change page layouts inside the document with (I suppose geometry works with inches, I've always used the metric system thus far):

```
\newgeometry{top=1in,bottom=in,left=1.5in,right=1in}
```

If you want to change to the previous layout afterward,use:

```
\restoregeometry
```

About the distance from the title, I guess you can change it from within the memoir class, you can find it in the manual.

Comment: The OP uses the `memoir` class which contains macros mirroring the functionality of the `geometry` package. Therefore I doubt the OP uses `geometry`.

Comment: Not that I know what the OP is but since memoir doesn't provide the needed functionality and should be compatible with the geometry package I don't see that it should be a problem.